# Unable to zoom map tile

Tags: mapserver, mapfile, mapcache

I try to host an OSM map locally on my server. I follow this tutorial [Rendering OSM on ubuntu](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataUbuntu) and managed to installed MapServer and MapCache.

The problem is, when I try to zoom the map it can only zoom once and other will just repeatedly create the same tile, sorry I couldn't post the image, since I'm new here.

What I understand is when I enter: `http://localhost/mapcache/demo/tms` the Apache web server will look for XML file (mapcache-osm.xml) and the XML file will find call the Mapfile and then it will generate the tile.

Is it true? Please correct me.

I still couldn't figure out how to make the zoom right, did I miss something on installation?

I also test the TMS on [OpenLayers site](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/tms.html) as recommended by the tutorial site. But the result is the same.

I thought if the Mapfile and database (PostGIS) connect successfully then it will generate the tile and I will be able to see all the tile at any zoom level. Or is there something that I need more to create the zoom features?

I found that if I enter `http://localhost/mapcache/demo/tms` then the XML file generate openlayers automatically. Am I wrong? Please correct me with the concept.